# Is there an equivalent ::file-selector-button for filename?

Tags: html, css

Where `input[type="file"]::file-selector-button` allows you to style the "Browse..." file selector button, is there a similar pseudo-element to allow for styling the selected filename (pseudo-)element?

Comment: What kind of style would you want to apply to it? You can always style the whole <input> in some way (including all the text related properties that would apply on the label, and style the button separately with ::file-selector-button.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to add `cursor: pointer`. By default only the File Selector Button has a pointer cursor. With `input[type="file"] { cursor: pointer }`, the area _around_ the text has the pointer, but the text itself still has the default cursor.

Comment: For this you can append your <input> in a parent <label>, set the cursor on it, and disable pointer-events on the <input> (the <label> will reroute its own to the <input>): https://jsfiddle.net/nst249kc/